# Extend a class with another class?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a package that defines `Bird`, `Eagle` and `Hawk` classes. `Eagle` and `Hawk` are subclasses of `Bird`.

I'd like to add some attributes to `Bird` class, but I don't want to change the package where the class is defined. I'm thinking to create a custom class `MyBird`.

```
e = Eagle(attr_eagle, attr_bird)
print(e.attr_eagle)
print(e.attr_bird)
```

Because `Eagle` inherits `Bird`, `e.attr_bird` works well. However I need another attribute that wasn't included in `Bird` class, name it `attr_mybird`. I want to write something like:

```
print(e.attr_mybird)
```

Comment: Please update your code with you definition of your `MyBird` class.

Comment: Why don't you do it by inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define new classes that inherit from other:

```
class Mybird(Bird):
    ...
```

Edit after comment:

If you want "normal" Eagle to have MyEagle attrs you need to modify underlying lib (why not?), or implement also your own MyEagle. Such MyEagle can inherit from Eagle (and add what you've added in MyBird); inherit from MyBird and add what makes MyEagle Eagle (probably harder, if you don't know source of lib) or use multiple inheritance, like:

```
class AddedFeature:
   ... # implement whatever you want to add to all birs here

class MyBird(Bird, AddedFeature):
   ... # will be Bird with added features from AddedFeature class

class MyEagle(Eagle, AddedFeature):
   ... # will be Eagle with added features from AddedFeature class
```

All in all what I would do is create your own fork of birds lib and implement your changes directly there. If it's something more people could benefit from, make a pull (merge) request to library author. If it's not the case, you can always have your fork published oninternal pypi, or "official" pypi while respecting original license (and changing name of package)

Comment: In this case Eagle inherits from Bird, so it has its and Bird attributes, but not MyBird attributes. So e.attr_mybird will not work, if e is an Eagle instance.